# Como faço para usar o window.open e window.close juntos

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo que quando uma pessoa aperte a tecla <kbd>shift</kbd> uma aba se abre e a anterior se fecha, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
<script>
    function keyCode(event) {
        var x = event.keyCode;
        var y = event.keyCode;
        if (x == 16) {  // 16 is the Shift key

           window.open('https://google.com.br' ,  '_blank')

           Window.close();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Mas só abre e não fecha a anterior.

Comment: Por padrão, a maioria dos navegadores não permitem que *scripts* fechem páginas abertas pelo usuário, por uma questão de segurança. Veja que ao tentar utilizar a função `close`, uma mensagem do tipo `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.` aparece no *console*. Apenas páginas abertas através do *script*, com a função `open`, podem ser fechadas. Leia mais na [especificação W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-window-close).

Comment: Mas testei seu script e não abriu nada no Chome, IE, Rdge, Firefox e Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você abre a janela, o foco passa para ela e o método **close()** é ignorado.

Coloque este código na janela que foi aberta (filha):

```
 window.opener.close();
```

Isso vai fechar a janela que a abriu (mãe).

Comment: eu Fiz isso mas nao deu certo ela abre a nova aba e a anterior nao e fechada 
OBS: nao e a janela seria no casso aki uma aba da mesma janela

Comment: Veja meu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199551/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-usar-o-window-open-e-window-close-juntos#comment409447_199551) para mais informações.